# Possible to connect JMeter perfMon to Glassfish's port 8686 for JMX monitoring?

Tags: glassfish, jmeter, perfmon, jmeter-plugins

I have a server that I am going to monitor, using [perfMon plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/PerfMon) for JMeter. I have Glassfish up and running which can provide me JMX details at port 8686, but I have trouble connecting my JMeter to this information. I have read that I can start up JVM with some parameters, but since Glassfish does this as well, is it not possible to get the readings there?

A little further explaining. I have a serverAgent started on my server which I want to monitor. I have JMeter on my machine, and I use URL's which is local, so no firewall issues. 
On my machine using JMeter, I set up a jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector this way:

```
Host:IP = the ip pointing to my serverAgent server, listening on 4444 default.  
Metric to collect = JMX  
Metric parameters: ?
```

According to Oracle, the url for GF JMX values should have a link looking like:

```
URL = service:jmx:rmi://localhost:8686/jndi/rmi://localhost:8686/jmxrmi|#]
```

I have tried this url in various ways, in hope to get this to work, but so far nothing. My serverAgent is screaming, No SIGAR object for metric type jmx, so it seems its possible it gets something fron GF on port 8686, but its no SIGAR object.

But it is possible for SIGAR to connect for this GF port, retrieving information for JMeter isnt it? Hyperic uses SIGAR iirc, and it connects just fine according to them :)

Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: Your server agent is screaming because JMX support was added in not yet released 0.5.2 version. You can try a snapshot: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/downloads/detail?name=JMeterPlugins-0.5.2-snapshot2.zip

Comment: You are absolutely correct, solved itself the second I used a 0.5.2 agent. Make your comment a post and I can "accept" your answer properly >)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use version less than 0.5.2

The solution is to upgrade to 0.5.2